# Сreate a full copy of the object from UpdateView or from ListView in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have Class Based views for my models. I want to create a full copy of the object and go to editing it. I would like to do this from UpdateView with a special button for copying, but it is a good option from the list of objects. How can I do this? Below is the code for one of the models.

My CreateView:

```
class CreateDealView(
    CustomSuccessMessageDeal,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    CreateView
):
        model = Deal
        template_name = 'db_visual/create_deal.html'
        form_class = DealForm
        permission_required = (
            'db_visual.add_deal',
        )
        success_message = "Сделка %(pk)s успешно создана!"
        def get_success_url(self):
            url_kwargs = {'deal_id': self.object.id}
            url_name = 'update_deal'
            return reverse_lazy(url_name, kwargs=url_kwargs)
```

My UpdateView:

```
class UpdateDealView(
    CustomSuccessMessageDeal,
    CustomPermissionRequired,
    UpdateView
):
    model = Deal
    pk_url_kwarg = 'deal_id'
    template_name = 'db_visual/update_deal.html'
    form_class = DealForm
    success_message = "Сделка <a href='%(url)s'>%(id)s</a> " \
                      "успешно изменена!"

    def get_success_url(self):
        url_name = 'deals'
        return reverse_lazy(url_name)

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            id=self.object.id,
            url=reverse_lazy(
                'update_deal',
                kwargs={
                    'deal_id': self.object.id,
                }
            ),
        )
```

UPD: I wrote a view for create copy by id, but when I try redirect to UpdateView I get error:

[image]

My view:

```
def copy_deal(request, deal_id):
    new_deal = Deal.objects.get(pk=deal_id)
    new_deal.pk = None
    new_deal.save()
    return reverse_lazy(
        'update_deal',
        kwargs={'deal_id': new_deal.pk}
    )
```

What's wrong with my reverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

`return reverse_lazy(
        'update_deal',
        kwargs={'deal_id': new_deal.pk}
    )` to

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(
        'update_deal',
        kwargs={'deal_id': new_deal.pk}
    ))`